# How do you show x items per row in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net

Anyone have any clue on how to show 4 items going horizontal with a repeater?  A repeater shows items going down by default.  Here is my test repeater code so far:

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align="center" width="800px;>
    <tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                        <h3><a href="<%#GetItemLink((Item)Container.DataItem) %>"><%#((WebMenuItem)Container.DataItem).Name %></a></h3>
                        <div>
                            <a href="<%#GetUrl((Item)Container.DataItem) %>">
                                <img src="<%#GetImage((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" alt="<%#GetAltText((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this tabular data, or data that you would just like to show in a 4 column, many row grid?  Like picture thumbnails for example.

Comment: All, I want to use a repeater, nothing else.

Comment: this is tabular data but pictures and text, not just text for showing products in a grid, 4 per row.

Answer (score 21):

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater id="rptTest" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty %>
                <td>
                    ... cell contents omitted ...
                </td>
            <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>" : string.Empty %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Long live the humble repeater!

Comment: @Jeff Sternal I tried your solution, but it give me error, why?

Comment: @Alaa: if you provide some more information here or post it as a question, I'll have a better chance of helping you.

Answer (score 6):

Modifying Nick's suggestion I was able to use to make a 5 horizontal x *n* vertical Image Grid. Thanks Nick!

```
<asp:Repeater ID="colorsList" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex % 5 == 0) ? @"</tr><tr>" : string.Empty %>
        <td>
        <div><img src="<%#ColorThumbnailImage((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COLOR_SQUARE_IMAGE")) %>" /></div>
        <div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COLOR_NAME") %></div>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tr></table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And here's ColorThumbnailImage

```
 protected string ColorThumbnailImage(string fileName)
{
    return Request.ApplicationPath + MySports.System.Configuration.ColorSquareImageLocation + fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Scott Guthrie provided an example of how to do this with a ListView control in the following [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx).  He uses the control to render an unordered list and uses CSS to control the layout.

Comment: Good choice - there's an ability to group items together... +1

Answer (score 2):

Using DataList control with RepeatColumns property might be simpler :

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 4;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a ListView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    GroupItemCount="5">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1">
      <tr runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder">
      </tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <GroupTemplate>
    <tr runat="server" id="tableRow">
      <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </tr>
  </GroupTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server">
      <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
      <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
    </td>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a CSS class for your `<td>` tags, and set an explicit width.

Comment: that has no bearing. A repeater will repeat down by default even if the width is tight on each item.

Comment: that's not true, the point of a Repeater template is to render your own custom HTML, and it is the browser that interprets how to render it. It's all about how the HTML that gets sent to the browser is constructed and what rules are defined that tells the browser how to render properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job (I'm assuming you may have more than one row of four images):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align="center" width="800px">
<tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex % 4 == 0) ? @"</tr><tr>" : string.Empty %>
<td>
<h3><a href="<%#GetItemLink((Item)Container.DataItem) %>"><%# (WebMenuItem)Container.DataItem).Name %></a></h3>
<div>
<a href="<%#GetUrl((Item)Container.DataItem) %>"><img src="<%#GetImage((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" alt="<%#GetAltText((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" /></a>
</div>
</td>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</tr>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

(no IDE so untested :)

If it doesn't help, some answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560023/asp-net-repeater-template-conditional-code-for-every-nth-element) might.