# How can i spread Database cells over the same html row + skip to a new row every number of records?

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, gridview, repeater

i have a `database table` containing `ID` and `Name`.
in Default.aspx i only show the `Name` cell (column) off the DB table, this is not a big deal.

But GridView generates an html table like this (of course i removed gridview header):
------------
| Name 1 |
------------
| Name 2 |
------------
| Name 3 |
------------

### My questions

How can i let the above GridView:
1 - to spread the Names over `1 row`?
2 - and to skip to a `new row` `every 2 records` (every 2 names)?

#### What i tried and failed:

- I tried to to use a repeater instead of GridView and i wrote 2 `<td>`, but unfortunately, as you can see, though it will skip every 2 names but it will show the same name (same record) twice.

```asp
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("name")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("name")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

- I also tried to move `<tr>` and `</tr>` to HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate, it now does show them all on 1 row but unfortunately it doesn't create a new row every 2 Names:

```asp
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
   <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
           <td><%# Eval("name")%></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dead set on using a `Repeater`, look at the first answer for this SO question:

[How do you show x items per row in a repeater?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765942/how-do-you-show-x-items-per-row-in-a-repeater)

A much simpler approach would be using the `DataList` control. It has built-in ability to break items across rows using these two properties:

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 2;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the first answer in that page looks vague. But the DataList answer is simple for newbies and does the job well.

Comment: IMHO, the `DataList` is not just for "newbies". It is the correct way to do what you are trying to accomplish. It seems to me that all the other answers are "work-arounds" to do exactly what the `DataList` was designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only looking for 2, you can use the alternating item template.

```
      <AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <td>
            <%# Eval("name")%>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </AlternatingItemTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%# Eval("name")%>
          </td>
      </ItemTemplate>
```

You may have to swap the <tr> and the </tr> tags

Comment: thank you so much but what if i need to move to a new row with every 3 or 4 records? i can't get alternating item template to work in this case. any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming before you bind your data to the GridView you have your data in a DataTable or DataReader - You could loop through the datasource and contruct a new DataTable with 3 columns, which will hold names, then bind that to the grid.

Psuedo example for 3:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.columns.add("name1");
dt.columns.add("name2");
dt.columns.add("name3");

int pointer = 1;
DataRow dr = null;

for(int i=0;i<sourceTable;i++)
{
    if( pointer==1 )
    {
        dr = dt.newRow();
        dr["name1"] = sourceTable.Rows[i]["Name"];
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        pointer++;
    }
    else if( pointer==2)
    {
        dr["name2"] = sourceTable.Rows[i]["Name"];
        pointer++;
    }
    else
    {
        dr["name3"] = sourceTable.Rows[i]["Name"];
        pointer=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't currently understand the example of DataTable and DataReader as I'm still currently learning but I'm sure someone else will find it useful. Thank you dave823.