# Bind 3 items in each row of a repeater VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this code that creates a check box an image and a label.

I want to view only three cells in each row, how can I do that??

```
   <table class="checkbox-container" style="margin-top: 15px; width: 50%;">
       <tr>
           <asp:Repeater EnableViewState="true" ID="rptStart" runat="server">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <td style="width:25%;">
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColor" runat="server" />
                       <img id="imgCompStatusStar" runat="server" enableviewstate="false" src="../images/" />
                       <asp:Label id="lblStarDescription" class="floating-left" runat="server" CssClass="test"/>
                   </td>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to put each control in a different cell? or how to only bind three items from your data set?

Comment: cell1: c.b img lbl  cell2: c.b img lbl cell3: c.b img lbl  like that I mean , bind three items from your data set @Pow-Ian

Comment: <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty %>  I tried that, but it raise an error

Comment: Does it have to be a table?  A cas solution would work.

Comment: no , the table is not important, it is for view issues. @ Daniel Gimenez

Comment: There is a similar question, [How do you show x items per row in a repeater](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5527778/690329)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your markup to this:

```
<asp:Repeater EnableViewState="true" ID="rptStart" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#If((Container.ItemIndex <> 0 AndAlso Container.ItemIndex Mod 3 = 0), "</tr><tr>", String.Empty)%>
    <td style="width: 25%;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColor" runat="server" />
        <img id="imgCompStatusStar" runat="server" enableviewstate="false" src="../images/" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblStarDescription" class="floating-left" runat="server" CssClass="test" />
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </tr></table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: No, in repeater you can do this. Did you try it?

Comment: Look at this answer [How to create a three column table in ASP.Net Repeater](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12986396/690329)

Comment: why this sentence raise an error??

 <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 3) % 3 == 0 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty%>

Comment: Where and why do you need this?

Comment: Thank you @afzalulh,  I made a little change to your code and it is working well now.