# How to modify layout using an Asp.net Repeater

Tags: html, asp.net, repeater

I have a table in my DB that has 2 columns "Car" & "Color".

In my Asp.net application, I have a repeater within my table. The repeater looks like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater_CarsColors" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                      <td>                       
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Car" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Car")%>'/>                              
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Color" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Color")%>'/>                    
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Right now, it is displaying the results as such:

[image]

How can I modify my repeater so that, instead of having 1 item per row, I can have multiple ones as such:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to do that by css.  Look at bootstrap fluid layout

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766379/1309182).

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater id="rptTest" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty %>
                <td>
                    ... cell contents omitted ...
                </td>
            <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>" : string.Empty %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

credit to original poster.

Cheers!